# Passing multiple Objects to method in JAVA

Tags: java

Im tried to passing 2 Objects defined (Transaction with one attribute "amount") to another method that will receive the list of Transaction

This is the main:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    // Here is when the Transaction was sent twice with differents amounts
    BankAccount saving = new SavingAccount("Raul", 1000d, new Transaction(500d), new Transaction(-500d));
}
```

}

This is the Object Transaction

```
class Transaction {

    private Double amount;
    public Transaction(Double amount) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
```

}

and This is the Bank class

```
class BankAccount {

private String name;
private Double amount;

public BankAccount(String name, Double amount) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(Double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

}

and finally the SavingAccount will do some operations with the List of transactions

```
class SavingAccount extends BankAccount{
public SavingAccount(String name, Double amount, List<Transaction> transaction) {
    super(name, amount);
    // Do something with the list of transactions
}
```

}

My first solution was to create a List of type Transaction and pass to the method and it Works, but my solution was rejected...

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    List<Transaction> transaction = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    transaction.add(new Transaction(5000d));
    transaction.add(new Transaction(-5000d));
    BankAccount saving = new SavingAccount("Raul", 1000d, transaction);
}
```

}

How can i do to maintain the send of that objects as parameters without define a ArrayList first?

Comment: What do you mean when you say your solution was rejected? Was there an auto-grader? Try looking up [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), which let you basically enter as many arguments as you want (although it's really just an array, so it's not much different from you using an `ArrayList`)

Comment: When dealing with money, arbitrary-precision is important. So, use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) over double in such a scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the signature of your SavingAccount constructor to use varargs that receive how many Transaction objects that you want:

```
 public SavingAccount(String name, BigDecimal amount, Transaction ... transactions) {}
```

Or you can use simply two Transaction objects:

```
public SavingAccount(String name, BigDecimal amount, Transaction transaction1, Transaction transaction2) {}
```